# Python Shapely Cant Find Points Within Polygon When Looping Polygons

Tags: python, geojson, shapely

I have a **csv file** of store locations with lat and lon. I also have a **geojson** file with polygon features of US Census tracts. I want to use **Python** to see in which polygons each location exists.

I am using **Shapely** Python library's contains() to loop through the csv file of store locations, grab lat and lon coordinates, and then check if the coordinates exist within one of the polygons from a geojson file.

The code I have works successfully if I loop through each location/coordinate first, then loop through each polygon, using contains() or within() to check if a polygon contains the point.

But this is too slow, so I want to inverse the process and loop through the polygons/geojson file first, and check the hundreds of thousands of polygons against the thousands of coordinates, instead of the other way around.

However, when I simply switch the loops to check the polygons against the coordinates, contains() does not find any matches, even though it finds correct matches when I loop through coordinates first and check them against polygons. It's the same code, except reversed.

Code (contains brings up false):

```
with open(mapFile) as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    #Loop through features in Geojson file
    for feature in data['features']:

        polygon = shape(feature["geometry"])

        for row in locationsFile:
            #get point coordinates from file
            pointLat = float(row[13])
            pointLon = float(row[14])

            point = Point(pointLon, pointLat)

            print(polygon.contains(point))   
            if polygon.contains(point):

                #Grab data
                newx = feature["properties"]["x"]
                newy = feature["properties"]["y"]
                newz = feature["properties"]["z"]
                #append data
                row.append(newx)
                row.append(newy)
                row.append(newz)
                #update file
                newFile.writerow(row)
                break
```

This code produces accurate results:

```
with open(mapFile) as f:
    data = json.load(f)

    #Loop through coordinates in CSV file
    for row in locationsFile:
        #get point coordinates from file
        pointLat = float(row[13])
        pointLon = float(row[14])

        point = Point(pointLon, pointLat)

        #Loop through features in Geojson file
        for feature in data['features']:

            polygon = shape(feature["geometry"])

            if polygon.contains(point):

                #Grab data
                newx = feature["properties"]["x"]
                newy = feature["properties"]["y"]
                newz = feature["properties"]["z"]
                #append data
                row.append(newx)
                row.append(newy)
                row.append(newz)
                #update file
                newFile.writerow(row)
                break
```

Answer (score 0):

`break` will behave differently in both cases. It will only break out of the innermost loop, which in the "correct" case, is the loop through `data['features']`, but in the incorrect case, is the loop through `locationsFile`